# React app not rendering after transpiling with webpack (BabelJS) part 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

This post is an extension of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368147/react-app-not-rendering-after-transpiling-with-webpack-babeljs)   on the same problem. My react code is still not rendering, but I have new information gathered from my troubleshooting efforts:

1) A responder from the last post got my code to work in his environment. To match his environment I downloaded babel-core, babel-loader, and babel-preset-2015. I also changed my version of webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname, 
    entry: "./src/App.js",

    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: __dirname + "/assets"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2) The problem is not related to the server because heroku successfully delivers all files.

3) It's not a browser-related issue since the app doesn't render in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

All I can think of is that the problem is related to webpack/babel, but do you guys have any other ideas??

Comment: Does your static resources loaded into browser?

Comment: My html loads, but not my javascript. The javascript is recieved with a 200 status, but it is not restructuring the DOM to add the react component.

Answer (score 0):

From going to the url: https://dry-river-67944.herokuapp.com/

It looks like your js file is not getting sent down. Instead the get request handler for `/:input` is being used for that request.

```
app.get("/:input", (req, res) => {
    //Assign headerVal to Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")

    //Send response data
    var convertedData = timestampMicroServ(req.params.input)
    res.end(convertedData)
})
```

Should be put after your staticfile middleware or namespaced (`/api/:input`?):

```
app.get("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/TMS-Front-End/assets')))
```